# How can I check what kind of video card I have?

Tags: command-line, video, hardware, 9.04

Is there any command line or program in Ubuntu 9.04 I can use to get information about my video card?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo lspci|grep VGA
```

shows me I have a:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]
```

If you want even more information you can install [mesa-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mesa-utils) [image: Install mesa-utils]. Besides the obvious things:

```
$ glxinfo|grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series

$ glxinfo|grep vendor
server glx vendor string: ATI  
client glx vendor string: ATI  
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
```

It will show about 3 pages of information about the driver in use.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `lspci` you can use [hwinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hwinfo) [image: Install hwinfo] which is quite a useful tool for getting detailed information about all kinds of hardware components, and their drivers, on your system.

By default `hwinfo` prints out quite long list of information but you can specify what you want by:

```
hwinfo --gfxcard
```

Other options are:

```
all,  bios,  block,  bluetooth,  braille,  bridge, camera, 
cdrom, chipcard,  cpu,  disk,  dsl,  dvb,  fingerprint,  floppy,
framebuffer,  gfxcard,  hub,  ide,  isapnp, isdn, joystick, 
keyboard, memory, modem, monitor, mouse, netcard,  network,  
partition,  pci,  pcmcia, pcmcia-ctrl, pppoe, printer, scanner, 
scsi, smp, sound, storage-ctrl, sys, tape,  tv,  usb,  usb-ctrl,  
vbe, wlan, and zip.
```

For more information

```
man hwinfo
```